# Get values from component child to component father using angular2

Tags: angular, get, components

I have developed an autocomplete in my child component, which I include several times in the parent component, everything works correctly, now I have a question of how to get the selected value of each autocomplete from my parent component. I want it when I click the search button, retrieve the values in the method "popupCopyLookupModel ()" but when I ask for "this." + "and the autocomplete name" always returns me undefined. I think this part is not doing it right. Any ideas?
autocomplete.component.ts (component child):

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-autocomplete',
templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./autocomplete.component.css'],
host: {
    '(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)',
},
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() public filteredList = [];

private estilosListaAC = new EstilosLista();
private propiedadesListaAC = new PropiedadesLista();
private propiedadesInputAC = new PropiedadesInput();
@Input() opciones : OpcionesAutocomplete;  

//Origen de datos, se lo pasamos desde el componente padre:
@Input() dataSource:any[];
@Input() dataSubject:Subject<any[]>;
@Input() propiedad1:string = "";
@Input() propiedad2:string = "";
@Input() classInput:string = "";
@Input() textoLabel:string = ""; 


//Valor tecleado en el input:
public query = '';
public elementRef; 
private _dataSource:any[];    
private _opciones:OpcionesAutocomplete;

getData(): Observable<any[]> {
if (this.dataSubject) 
{
  return this.dataSubject.asObservable();
}
else
{
  return Observable.of([]);
}
} 

//El propio componente:
constructor(myElement: ElementRef) {
  this.elementRef = myElement;
}    

ngOnInit() {  
//Establecemos el origen de datos que nos llega del componente padre:
this._dataSource = this.dataSource;
this.getData().subscribe((x) => {
  if (x && x.length > 0)
    this._dataSource = x;
  },
  error => { console.log("Error en al recuperar datos en Autocomplete") }
);
//Establecemos las opciones por defecto, si no nos llegan del componente padre, cogemos las definidas en este propio componente:    
if (this.opciones instanceof OpcionesAutocomplete){
  this._opciones = this.opciones;
  if (this._opciones.propiedadesLista instanceof PropiedadesLista){
    this.propiedad1 = this._opciones.propiedadesLista.propiedad1;
    this.propiedad2 = this._opciones.propiedadesLista.propiedad2;
  }
  if (this._opciones.propiedadesInput instanceof PropiedadesInput){
    this.textoLabel = this._opciones.propiedadesInput.texto;
    this.classInput = this._opciones.propiedadesInput.class;
  }
}else{
  this.textoLabel = "Sin Configurar";
}     
} 

//Se lanza cuando se selecciona un elemento de la lista:
select(item){
  //this.query = item
  if (item[this._opciones.propiedadesLista.propiedad1] !== undefined)
  {
      this.query = item[this._opciones.propiedadesLista.propiedad1]
  }
  if (item[this._opciones.propiedadesLista.propiedad2] !== undefined) {
      this.query = this.query + ' ' + item[this._opciones.propiedadesLista.propiedad2];
  }
  //this.query  = item.propiedad1 + item.propiedad2;
  this.filteredList = [];
}
}
```

busquedacopiadora.component.html (component father):

```
<app-autocomplete id="selectCliente" [dataSubject]="clientesSub"      
    [dataSource]="clientes"> 
</app-autocomplete>

<app-autocomplete id="selectProveedor" [dataSubject]="proveedoresSub"  
    [dataSource]="proveedores" [opciones]="opcionesAutocompleteProveedores"> 
</app-autocomplete>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary botonBuscar" 
(click)="rellenarCopiadoraBusquedaModel($event)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
</button>
```

busquedacopiadora.component.ts (component father):

```
rellenarCopiadoraBusquedaModel() 
{
    if (this.selectCliente !== undefined && this.selectCliente !== 0) 
    {                
       console.log('Cliente: ' + this.selectCliente);
    }

    if (this.selectProveedor !== undefined && this.selectProveedor !== 0) 
    {                
        console.log('Cliente: ' + this.selectProveedor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ViewChild decorator (in case of single autocomplete) or ViewChildren in case of multiple
For example

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {  @ViewChild(HeaderComponent)header: HeaderComponent;
```

Here you tell Angular to grab the reference of any child HeaderComponent type.
From that reference you can access all properties of the component in the parent.

Comment: I resolved it creating a EventEmmiter from component child. Thank you because i didn´t khow the "@ViewChild" decorator.